# Why my search bar isnt working? Javascript - Web

Tags: javascript, search, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a real-estate web app. I am about to finish it but i am stuck on this last thing. I have added a search bar in my homepage which makes the user filter the properties based on the city, rent/sale, min-rooms/max-rooms, min-price and max-price. I am wondering why the search bar isnt working?
This is my search bar:

```
<!-- Search Section -->
        <form class="col s8 l1" onsubmit="filteredPrices(li)">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s4 l2">
                    <select class="all-cities">
                      <option value="">Choose...</option>
                      <option value="1">Adana</option>
                      <option value="2">Adıyaman</option>
                      <option value="3">Afyonkarahisar</option>
                      <option value="4">Ağrı</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s4 l2">
                    <select class="rent-sale" >
                        <option value="0">Type</option>
                        <option value="Rent">Rent</option>
                        <option value="Sale">Sale</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="input-field col s5 l2">
                    <select class="min-rooms">
                        <option value="0">Min Rooms</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>  
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s5 l2">
                    <select class="max-rooms">
                        <option value="0">Max Rooms</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s4 l2">
                    <input type="text" id="min" placeholder="Min price $">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s4 l2">
                    <input type="text" id="max" placeholder="Max price $">
                </div> 

            </div>
            <button class="btn waves-effect indigo right" type="submit">Search
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
              </button>
        </form><!-- ./Search Section -->
```

And here is where i am adding the properties from cloud firestore to my home page:

```
const setupProp = data => {
  let html = '';
  data.forEach(doc => {
    const info = doc.data();
    let li = `
    <div class="col s12 l4 items">
      <div class="card" style="height: 407px;">
        <div class="card-image">
          <a href="property.html?${doc.id}">
          <img src="${info.image[0]}" style="height: 228px;"></a>
          <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red center status">${info.type}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <span><b class="house-title">${info.title}</b></span><br>
          <span><b class="blue-text price">${info.price}</b> &#36;</span><br>
          <span class="material-icons blue-text">room</span>
          <span><b class="city">${info.city}</b></span><br>
          <span class="material-icons blue-text">single_bed</span>
          <span><b class="rooms">${info.rooms}</b> rooms</span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    `;
    filteredPrices(li)
    html += li

    showingProp.innerHTML = html; 
  })
}
```

And finally here is my js search code:

```
const filteredPrices = li => {
            const searchMin = Number(document.getElementById('min').value); // Min price search tap
            const searchMax = Number(document.getElementById('max').value); // Max price search tap
            const rentSale = document.querySelector('.rent-sale').value; // Rent/Sale search tap
            const allCities = document.querySelector('.all-cities').value; // City search tap
            const minRooms = document.querySelector('.min-rooms').value; // Min rooms search tap
            const maxRooms = document.querySelector('.max-rooms').value; // Max rooms search tap

            const str = li;
            const temp = document.createElement('div');
            temp.innerHTML = str;
            // console.log(temp)
            const items = temp.querySelectorAll('.items');
            items.forEach(item => {
                const price = Number(item.querySelector('.price').textContent);
                const status = item.querySelector('.status').textContent;
                const city = item.querySelector('.city').textContent;
                const rooms = Number(item.querySelector('.rooms').textContent);

                if (price < searchMin || price > searchMax || rentSale !== status || allCities !== city
                        || rooms < minRooms || rooms > maxRooms) {
                        item.style.display = 'none';
                        // document.querySelector('.error').style.display = "block";
                        } else
                        item.style.display = 'block';
            })            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app.js you are declaring li in a limited scope, you are declaring it in setupProp() so the variable is valid just for setupProp() scope. Declare it outside setupProp() and outside of any other function, so the variable can be visible globally. Have Fun! [MDN let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)
P.S. next time do not forget to make known the error it gives you, otherwise there is much more work to do, by notifying the exact error the problem is limited!
**app.js code:**

```
const loggedOutLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.logged-out');
const loggedInLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.logged-in');
const showingProp = document.querySelector('.showing-prop');
const propShow = document.querySelector('.all-properties');

const setupUI = (user) => {
  if (user) {
    loggedInLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'block');
    loggedOutLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');
  } else {
    loggedInLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');
    loggedOutLinks.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'block');
  }
}

let li; //DECLARE li AS GLOBAL, NOT LOCAL INSIDE A FUNCTION
// Displaying the properties to the HomePage
const setupProp = data => {
  let html = '';
  data.forEach(doc => {
    const info = doc.data();
    li = `
    <div class="col s12 l4 items">
      <div class="card" style="height: 407px;">
        <div class="card-image">
          <a href="property.html?${doc.id}">
          <img src="${info.image[0]}" style="height: 228px;"></a>
          <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red center status">${info.type}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <span><b class="house-title">${info.title}</b></span><br>
          <span><b class="blue-text price">${info.price}</b> &#36;</span><br>
          <span class="material-icons blue-text">room</span>
          <span><b class="city">${info.city}</b></span><br>
          <span class="material-icons blue-text">single_bed</span>
          <span><b class="rooms">${info.rooms}</b> rooms</span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    `;
    filteredPrices(li)
    html += li

    showingProp.innerHTML = html; 
  })
}


// Displaying the properties to the Properties Page(Subpage)
const setupSub = data => {

  const id = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
  data.forEach(doc => {
    if(doc.id === id) {
    let info = doc.data();
    const images = info.image.map(img => {
      return `
         <a href="#" class="carousel-item">
            <img src=${img} alt="istanbul"  style="height: 390px;">
         </a>
      `;
});
    let html = `
    <div class="row" >
            <div class="col l6 s12 m12">
                <div class="carousel carousel-slider" data-indicators ="true" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                ${images.join('')}
                </div>
                  <div class="btn indigo waves-affect prev">Prev</div>
                  <div class="btn indigo waves-affect right next">Next</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col l6 s12 m12">
                <div class="card" style="height: 357px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #f9f9f9; padding: 10px;">
                      <h5 class="center">${info.title}</h5><br><br>
                      <span style="font-weight: bold;"><span class="blue-text">Price:</span> ${info.price} &#36;</span><br><br>
                      <span><i class="material-icons blue-text">room</i> Located in ${info.city}.</span><br><br>
                      <span><i class="material-icons blue-text">single_bed</i> Total Rooms ${info.rooms}.</span><br><br>

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
      `;
        // To activate the image slider (Materialize css)
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.carousel').carousel();

          // function for next slide
          $('.next').click(function(){
              $('.carousel').carousel('next');
          });

          // function for prev slide
          $('.prev').click(function(){
              $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
          });
  });


      propShow.innerHTML = html;
  }
  })
}
```